# how to translate each and every row of csv file

Tags: python, django, csv, language-translation, translators

some words of the row are getting translated, sometimes and sometimes not.

```
from googletrans import Translator
myfile=open("ElectricCarData_Norm.csv")
f=myfile.readlines()

translator=Translator()  
with open("Electric.csv", 'w',encoding="utf-8") as op:      
  for line in f:
    #print(line)
    translation = translator.translate(line, src='en',dest='hi').text
    
  #print(line," ",translation)
    op.write(translation)
    op.write('\n')
```

Comment: Probably the problem is that you translator doesn't know the translation and leaves the word unchanged.

Comment: But it is translating for some occurrence of a particular word. It means the translator knows the translation of the word.